# SOSL unusual behaviour

Tags: sosl

I have faced and have been facing issues using the SOSL query or I may say SOSL query confuses me every time with its result/output.

i have encountered situations when the SOSL search query doesn't return result when search is made over a record having proper search values.

Recently i faced the following issue:

[image: Search with No Result]

[image: Search with Result]

1. In the first Image, i tried searching an Account with the id value. 
   **Result**: No search Result.
2. I then tried using a different field's value to search the same record.
   **Result**: The record shows Up.

Its an unusual behaviour and I think this happens with me, as I found no similar question on SOSL.

Help me understand the situation.